# How to fetch data from drop down menu and pass to pop out dialog ? [Blazor]

Tags: c#, blazor

I have one drop-down menu with Id and I want to pass it to a pop-out dialog. For example, if I choose the data from the drop-down menu which is "JOHN", "JOHN" will be passed to the pop-out dialog when I press the Create Button, which the text field will be Name: "JOHN"

This is my drop-down menu: CodeDetails.razor

```
<MudAutocomplete Dense="true" T="int" Style="background-color: transparent; color: transparent;" Label="@_localizer["CodeDescription"]" For="@(() => AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId)" @bind-Value="AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" SearchFunc="@SearchCodes" Variant="Variant.Outlined" ToStringFunc="@(i => _codes.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == i)?.CodeDescription ?? string.Empty)" OffsetY="true" />
```

and want to pass to the pop-out dialog Text Field: AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor

```
<MudTextField ReadOnly="true" T="int" Label="@_localizer["CodeType"]" For="@(() => AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId)" @bind-Value="AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" Variant="Variant.Outlined"  OffsetY="true" />
```

Both are at different razor components.

Can someone teach me, please?

I have added a parameter on AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor.cs

```
[Parameter] public static CodeDetails CodeId { get; set; }
```

And Edit the Drop-down menu

```
<MudAutocomplete Dense="true"  Style="background-color: transparent; color: transparent;" Label="@_localizer["CodeDescription"]" For="(() => AddEditCodeDetailModal.CodeId)" @bind-Value="AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" SearchFunc="@SearchCodes" Variant="Variant.Outlined" ToStringFunc="@(i => _codes.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == i)?.CodeDescription ?? string.Empty)" OffsetY="true" />
```

And set the bind-value in TextField: AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor

```
<MudTextField ReadOnly="true"  Label="@_localizer["CodeType"]" For="@(() => AddEditCodeDetailModel.CodeId)" @bind-Value="CodeId" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" Variant="Variant.Outlined"  OffsetY="true" />
```

and I got these error

> CS1662    Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type
> because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return
> type  Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\Catalog\AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor.g.cs 323 Active
>
> CS0411    The type arguments for method
> 'TypeInference.CreateMudTextField_1(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int,
> bool, int, string, int, Expression<Func>, int, object, int,
> Variant, int, object, int, T, int, EventCallback)' cannot be
> inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.   Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\Catalog\AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor.g.cs 533 Active
>
> CS0411    The type arguments for method
> 'TypeInference.CreateMudAutocomplete_0(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int,
> bool, int, string, int, string, int, Expression<Func>, int, bool,
> int, Func<string, Task<IEnumerable>>, int, Variant, int, Func<T,
> string>, int, bool, int, T, int, EventCallback)' cannot be inferred
> from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.   Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\Catalog\CodeDetails.razor.g.cs    325 Active
>
> CS0411    The type arguments for method
> 'TypeInference.CreateMudTextField_1(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int,
> bool, int, string, int, Expression<Func>, int, object, int,
> Variant, int, object, int, T, int, EventCallback)' cannot be
> inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.   Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\Pages\Catalog\AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor 1   Active
>
> CS1662    Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type
> because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return
> type  Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\Pages\Catalog\AddEditCodeDetailModal.razor 1   Active
>
> CS0411    The type arguments for method
> 'TypeInference.CreateMudAutocomplete_0(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int,
> bool, int, string, int, string, int, Expression<Func>, int, bool,
> int, Func<string, Task<IEnumerable>>, int, Variant, int, Func<T,
> string>, int, bool, int, T, int, EventCallback)' cannot be inferred
> from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.   Client  C:\Users\yjing\source\repos\BlazorHeroPWA\src\Client\Pages\Catalog\CodeDetails.razor    1   Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two components are in the same scope (Page or Component), you can create a variable that holds the selected value of drodownlist and the popup should bind with this variable.

If they are in different contexts, you can use [Parameter] or something like that.

[image: Here you have a Page (parent Component)]

In DDL Component, we have:

[image]

We receive a CallbackEvent to send the selectedItem to parent.
The parent receives the value and set it in a new variable and then passes it to the POP component.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have edit the question, can you have a look please